# How to respond to a boolean type in sanic?

Tags: python-3.x, sanic

I need to respond directly to True or False. How can I do this? Json, text, raw.... can't
code

```
if param == signature:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sanic/server.py", line 337, in 
write_response
response.output(
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'output'
```

Append:

```
from sanic.response import json, text

@service_bp.route('/custom', methods=['GET'])
async def cutsom(request):
    signature = request.args['signature'][0]
    timestamp = request.args['timestamp'][0]
    nonce = request.args['nonce'][0]

    token = mpSetting['custom_token']
    param = [token, timestamp, nonce]
    param.sort()
    param = "".join(param).encode('utf-8')
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    sha1.update(param)
    param = sha1.hexdigest()
    print(param, signature, param == signature)

    if param == signature:
        return json(True)
    else:
        return json(False)
```

I just want to simply return True or False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()


@app.route("/myroute")
async def myroute(request):
    param = request.raw_args.get('param', '')
    signature = 'signature'
    output = True if param == signature else False
    return json(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=7777)
```

You just need to wrap your response in [`response.json`](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/response.html#json).

These endpoints should work as expected:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:7777/myroute 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: 5
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/json

false
```

And

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:7777/myroute\?param\=signature

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: 5
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: application/json

true
```

Comment: I tried,response.json,text,raw... , but it can't work for me

Comment: I use it like this, return response.json(True)

Comment: @JohnDoe. Can you edit your question to post a snippet of your function so we can test it? The above in my (edited) answer does work.

Comment: I added my code, can I return `response.json(True)` directly? According to the return results of the server does not seem to be possible.

Comment: I verified it, it can return true, false, it may be that the relay server parsed the problem, but thank you!